# Windows 10 root causes: Upgrade path or app compatibility?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

**The Problem:**

Especially since the March 2016 update to Win10, my machine has had a continual stream of problems. The Event Viewer logs many common Windows 10 issues that Google can find 1000's of sketchy solutions for.  Generally a re-boot once or twice a day will allow me to keep working.  The variety of errors is huge, but typical ones include:

- Start Menu stops working
- The program ShellExperienceHost.exe / Microsoft.Photos.exe / SearchUI.exe/  ... stopped interacting with Windows and was closed.
- Activation of app Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge failed with error: The remote procedure call failed
- Activation of app Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaUI failed with error: The app didn't start in the required time. See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational

I've noticed Windows 10 is much fussier about file associations and registry settings being set by apps, especially when it comes to types that Windows wants to be handled by its apps like Edge or Photos. (e.g. .pdf, .jpeg where I'd rather use other software). TWinUI seems to be implicated in many of these problems.

This Lenovo T440s was upgraded from 8.1 to 10 in Nov 2015. I hardly use any Modern/Store apps.

**The Plan:**

Re-install Windows 10 and all applications from scratch. I have about 225 items installed, and of those over 150 are from Microsoft.  Re-paving this machine and configuring things will take a few days, so I only want to do this once.

**The Questions:**

- Are my problems more likely due to legacy incompatible software, or the 8.1 to 10 upgrade path this machine took?
- If the causes are older apps that are not truly Windows 10 compatible, what is the best way to empirically identify those apps? (Some just have no declared compatibility with Windows 10, but I need them.)
- Any other advice on getting Windows 10 working as a productive platform that includes older software?

Sorry for the length of this. I'm dreading the process and fearing the worst. TIA.

*Edit:* Some of the software installed: Visual Studio 2015, 2013, 2012, SQL Server 2012, Office 2007, WinZip 14.5, Acrobat XI, FileZilla, Fiddler, NodeJS, IrfanView, CloudBerry Explorer, Skype, SnagIt, Paint.Net, Git, SnagIt, Firefox, Chrome.

Comment: Are you on the Insider update path?  Perhaps the beta nature of Insider updates is causing problems.  it did for me.  A clean install helped, but subsequent updates screwed things up again.  Windows 10 still has issues to work out before its stable IMHO.

Comment: I think you mean November 2015.  Please edit you question.  We have no idea if your problems are caused by legacy software, you have 150 applications installed, and you don't specify a single one.

Comment: Yes, sorry @Ramhound, it was November 2015. And I'll update with some typical apps I have.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths  No Insiders versions were ever used - it is all mainstream releases.  Thx for report that you found the problems came back. I may just keep rebooting ...

Answer (score 0):

The 1607 ("Anniversary") update fixed these problems.

That update has received some bad press, but in this case it was the solution. I have not had the Start Menu stop working since the 1607 update 2.5 months ago. I did not do any re-installation, so this machine has gone via regular mainstream updates all the way from 8.1 to 1607.

The Event Viewer does very occasionally log an error similar to the ones listed in the original question but they have no discernible impact on the user experience.